# Words permutation with 'de' removal

Tags: prépositions, ordre-des-mots

In English, I can say both '*year of birth*' and '*birth year*', so can I feel free to swap related words in French deleting 'de', for example, from '*année de naissance*' to '*naissance an*'?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't, that kind of formulation doesn't exist in French.

Comment: as @LaurentS. said, you can't. When a French learns English, he learns the rule saying that *in english, you swap adjective and noun*, because it doesn't exist in french.

Comment: @Random, In this case there is no adjective. And actually sometimes, that  kind of inversion happens in French too ('une jolie maison' but 'un chat noir').

Comment: @vc74 The rule is not the same, in English class we swap adjective and noun **compared to French**.  The correct form in French (without exceptions for short adjectives and the *"apposition"*) is *noun* + *adjective* while in English it is *adjective* + *noun*.

Comment: @YohannV. Yes, that's the base rule but sometimes adjective/noun is used in French too: 'il a une jolie maison' for instance

Comment: @vc74 In [wiki](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntaxe_de_l'adjectif_en_fran%C3%A7ais) it is written that : *"La postposition est le cas le plus courant."*. So it's in relation to this fact that this *rules* was given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in French. *Année de naissance* is the only option.

Answer (score -1):

The first point is that [naissance](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/naissance) is a **noun**, so obviously, it cannot be used as an adjective.

Secondly, the idiom to translate *birth year* is *"année de naissance"* so **it is what you have to use** as @vc74 says.

Finally, if you really want to have an adjective related to birth, **even if it has not this meaning**, it would be *"native"*. 
 So the closest litteral translation of *birth year* could be *"année native"*.

Comment: If you say “année native” in France, you'll get a puzzled look.

Comment: @Gilles It is exactly what I said, I am just answering about the "hey I need a birth adjective". I clearly state that the idiom is "Année de naissance"